# Borrow checker and function arguments in Rust, correct or over zealous?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

When a mutable argument is passed as a function argument, the borrow checker doesn't allow this to be used to construct other arguments, even when those arguments clone values without holding a reference.

While assigning variables outside the function is always an option<sup>1</sup>, logically this seems over zealous and something the borrow checker could take into account.

Is this working as intended or something that should be resolved?

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct SomeTest {
    pub some_value: f64,
    pub some_other: i64,
}

fn some_fn(var: &mut SomeTest, other: i64) {
    println!("{:?}, {}", var, other);
}

fn main() {
    let mut v = SomeTest { some_value: 1.0, some_other: 2 };
    some_fn(&mut v, v.some_other + 1);

    // However this works!
/*
    {
        let x = v.some_other + 1;
        some_fn(&mut v, x);
    }
*/
}
```

Gives this error:

```
  --> src/main.rs:14:21
   |
14 |     some_fn(&mut v, v.some_other + 1);
   |                  -  ^^^^^^^^^^^^ use of borrowed `v`
   |                  |
   |                  borrow of `v` occurs here
```

See: [playpen](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=c5a21c7c17ee425dc7df4a641a89c58a&version=stable&backtrace=0).

---

[1]: Even though one-off assignments do sometimes improve readability, being forced to use them for arguments encourages use of scopes to avoid single use variables polluting the name-space, causing function calls that would otherwise be one line - being enclosed in braces and defining variables... I'd like to avoid this if possible especially when the requirement seems like something the borrow checker could support.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an artifact of the current implementation of the borrow checker. It is a well known limitation, dating back to *at least* 2013, and no one is overjoyed by it.

> Is this working as intended

Yes.

> something that should be resolved?

Yes.

The magic keywords are "non-lexical lifetimes". Right now, lifetimes are lexical - they correspond to the blocks of source that we type. Ideally, `foo.method(foo.mutable_method())` would see that the borrow ends "inside the parenthesis", but for a myriad of reasons, it is tied to the entire statement.

For tons of further information see [RFC issue 811](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/811) and everything linked from there.

Comment: I'm *certain* that this has been answered before, but I cannot find a duplicate. If you find it, let me know and I'll close it.

Comment: Wow, I've just stumbled on a very similar issue. It surprised me that `vec.drain(vec.len() - 1..)` is not allowed, while `let vlen = vec.len(); vec.drain(vlen - 1..)` compiles just fine. The workaround is trivial, but it feels wrong, as one could easily imagine the former practically *desugaring* into something like the latter. I assume the underlying cause is the same?

Comment: @user4815162342 yes.

Comment: Surprising this isn't high priority to resolve? AFAICS this is a fairly simple example where *borrow-checker-induced-damage* will be added to otherwise straightforward and safe code. I can understand that some complex scenarios will need workarounds, but this seems like a case that is likely to happen frequently. It also makes using methods more of a hassle then regular functions since accessing the method borrows too. Edit, maybe it is high priority - Issue 811 has >50 likes :)